# HPC Visualization node GPU choice

Tags: visualization, hpc

On most HPC Visualization node, we find nvidia tesla cards. P100 come to mind.

I'm not sure to follow why. Nvidia Tesla cards are designed for computing according to nividia [documentation](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/tesla-p100/), not for rendering. They even require a specific [configuration](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/hpc-visualization-nvidia-tesla-gpus/) to be able to render correctly.

Why not using a Titan card ? The Titan RTX seems perfect for the this usecase.

Related (but not duplicate) : [What are the differences between "scientific GPUs" and "gaming GPUs"?](https://superuser.com/questions/805217/what-are-the-differences-between-scientific-gpus-and-gaming-gpus)