# Does Nvidia rtx series still features plain cuda cores or is everything replaced by Tensor cores?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, cuda

For a long time, consumer Nvidia Graphic cards supportted having plain cuda cores despite not being branded for accelerators.

The problem in my case is while Tensor cores allow to perform cuda, they are restricted to matrix and less precise computations. This speeds up machine training and what depends on it like nvidia dlss.

On the new rtx series, I m no longer seeing any reference to the number of cuda cores (like rtx 3090 or rtx 3070).

Does it means things like deterministic cuda based rendering with Indigo Render now require Tesla gpu for newer cards?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXQiT.png output of the newest version of GPU-Z I could find for a 3080 from a partner.

Comment: @Ramhound this example scenario is not related to machine training. If the card no longer contains the less specialized hardware, things will run poorly if not at all.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I remember clearly seeing the cuda core count on gpu z with my Gtx 1070. Unfortunately the cpu fried and it doesn t fit in the new computer https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14184. On the other hand, there are reports of Blender renderer not detecting any OpenCl devices with those new consumer cards.

Comment: GPU Z detects OpenCL is supported on the 3080 - Version is Version OpenCL 1.2 CUDA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that the 3000 series, and presumably older RTX and GTX cards still have cuda cores, in addition to tensor and RT cores.

You can check the CUDA core count from the nvidia control panel, under system information

The RTX 3080 for example has 8704 CUDA cores listed

[image: screenshot of nvidia control panel]

If you don't have the exact card on hand, there's [lists](https://gist.github.com/sagnitude/c32a204dc698639e1ef54ad260f53449) you can use to look it up. WCCFtech has [specifications](https://wccftech.com/nvidia-rtx-3080-ti-9984-cuda-cores/) for some newer, and some speculative cards. For the models that are currently out as of Oct 2020, the numbers look correct, though

Comment: Great they even didn t decreased the count in order to leave room for the new features. Do you have an Nvidia replacement idea for that dumb problem https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3824869/96966840-d60f8980-150e-11eb-87e3-8ed989eebef3.jpg

Comment: I'm not quite getting what I am seeing. Is that a gaming card with wierd grubbins not fitting in a server case?

Comment: Yes, the problem is most card are large like this.